# Cloudera: Add the Accumulo 1.7.2 parcel into Cloudera manager

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, accumulo

I am trying to add the new accumulo 1.7.2 parcel for el7 into Cloudera manager. My version of Cloudera manager is 5.5.2 which is valid with the Accumulo parcel  (minimum is 5.5.0). And My cloudera machine have no internet connection

I downloaded the new parcel from this site: http://archive.cloudera.com/accumulo-c5/parcels/1.7.2/ACCUMULO-1.7.2-5.5.0.ACCUMULO5.5.0.p0.8-el7.parcel

I added the parcel into /opt/cloudera/parcel-repo/accumulo/
I have an older version of Accumulo there that is running fine. I also updated the manifest.json file include the SHA of the new parcel.
I am not able to see the parcel under Parcels in Cloudera manager.
I could not find any documentations about it.
How can I get the new Accumulo Parcel run with Cloudera manager?

Thank you

Comment: This is the installation guide: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/accumulo/latest/PDF/Apache-Accumulo-Installation-Guide-1-7-2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Keep `Accumulo parcel and manifest.json` in one directory, in the same location start simple python server `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`. Now open `Cloudera Manager --> parcel icon --> edit settings --> Remote Parcel Repository URLs`. In this windows you will see URI's like below[image]

Now click on `+` and add your ipaddress:8000. Then click on `Check for new parcels`